# Separating Emails Addresses

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list

I created a column in a List called 'NotificationEmails'.

The emails in the field are separated by a ',' (comma). is this appropriate/acceptable?

Or, should each email address in the field by separated by a ';' (semi-colon)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rule about using comma or semi-colon in this situation. It depends on how do you use this field.

For example, you have a program to run against this field (email) then have your program aware the separator is comma.

In my experience, Microsoft like to use semi-colon (e.g. Outlook) while Linux and Apple use comma. You may want to consider this part, too.